# Is insertion order preserved in MongoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have an array of objects that whenever I need them I want them to be sorted. So I have:

```
things.sort!

things.each do |thing|
  Thing.create!(property: some_property)
end
```

The `things` array are strings with the first letter from `a` to `z`. However, if I run the code above, the first item in my database starts with `m`, and then alphabetically goes to `z`, and then returns to `a`, and continues.

So is that to say the insertion order is not guaranteed to be preserved in MongoDB?

Comment: I would be surprised when MongoDB guaranteed to be preserve the insertion order. Even database like PostgreSQL or MySQL don't do that. If you rely on a certain order you need to tell the database to return the results in that specific order.

Comment: @spickermann If the result needs to be sorted each time I retrieve it, wouldn't be somewhat less efficient compared to sorting it only once at insertion? But I guess if MongoDB doesn't maintain the insertion order then that is probably the only solution.

Comment: I would argue that in most app the insertion order is not the order you would like to use to read your data. Most of the time you want something like order by a date, a number or a name, but usually not the timestamp of insertion. Use indexes to optimize reading the data in the way your application requires it. But each app needs different indexes, they are app specific and every app has different requirements and therefore an default like "by insertion order" doesn't make sense in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

No it does not preserve the insertion order.

The default sort order is the [natural order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order) which does not gurantee the insertion order.

Neither *["ObjectId values do not represent a strict insertion order"](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/bson-types/#objectid)*.

Comment: Then how the heck  is deleteOne or updateOne makes sense if we have to delete using a common key...    First of all ,  why there are two methods insertOne and insertMany ...why can't it be just "insert" method which will take as many records as we want and then inserts just like sql.